# Enqueueing Scripts and Styles

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to enqueue my custom script and style with the block of codes, the scripts works but not the style. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    function my_scripts_method() {

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
                    wp_deregister_script( 'style' );

            wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' );
                    wp_register_style( 'style', '//siteripe.com/style.css' );    
   }    


    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'my_style_method');
```

Comment: God's punishing you for unregistering jquery. :-) Joking, but deregistering jquery is really a worse practise. You have to `wp_enqueue_script` jquery, registering it's not enough to show it in a page.

Comment: @G.M.'s right, you don't want to deregister jquery in general.  What do you want from 1.7.2 that's not available in the version bundled with core?  I bet we can help you with the js.

Comment: Understood. The problem now is that it does not load the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wp_enqueue_style the wrong way as it is not an action hook. wp_enqueue_scripts action hook is being used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.
try this:

```
function my_scripts_method() {

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'style' );

        wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' );
        wp_register_style('style', '//siteripe.com/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style('style'); 
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```